# Oracle sqlplus like psql output

Tags: oracle-database

Is possible to get oracle sqlplus output like psql?
On psql i have perfectly ordered

```
    video=# select * from generale where titolo ~* 'brivido';
 idtitolo | titolo  | anno | genere | durata | formato |  lingua  
----------+---------+------+--------+--------+---------+----------
      653 | Brivido | 1986 | Orrore | 1:40   | Divx    | Italiano
```

On sqlplus(same table,same view)

```
          IDTITOLO|TITOLO              |ANNO                |GENERE
    ----------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------
    DURATA                                  |FORMATO             |LINGUA
    ----------------------------------------|--------------------|--------------------
           653|Brivido             |1986                |Orrore
    1:40                                    |Divx                |Italiano


1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

Very bad
This is my login.sql

```
set feedback on;
set linesize 100
set  colsep |
column titolo format a20
column anno format a20
column genere format a20
column formato format a20
column lingua format a20
--alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
set serveroutput on;
set autocommit off;
set pagesize 100;
set long 100;
set timing on;
alter session set cursor_sharing = 'EXACT'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,syntax correct
column "namecolumn" format aN where N is number of charatchers wich you expect to see
Now

SQL> select * from generale where titolo = 'Brivido';

```
  IDTITOLO|TITOLO            |ANNO   |GENERE      |DURATA                      |FORMATO   |LINGUA
----------|------------------------------|-------|------------|----------------------------------------|----------|----------
       653|Brivido           |1986   |Orrore      |1:40                    |Divx      |Italiano

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```